# beautiful soup find_all returns empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

when i run this i get a empty list, and i wanted to get wave height from [this](https://www.surfline.com/surf-report/meia-praia/5842041f4e65fad6a7708e84?view=table) website

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.surfline.com/surf-report/meia-praia/5842041f4e65fad6a7708e84?view=table")
c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
all = soup.find_all("h4", {"class":"MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-headline SurfCell_height__FkNCP mui-style-1sd06dx"})

print(all)
```

im trying to get the wave height but it keeps giving me empty list

Comment: You want to use the API. See: https://github.com/swrobel/meta-surf-forecast#surfline.

Comment: Check if `c` really contains the desired information. If not, it was added by JavaScript later to the DOM. In this case, you need something like Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_driver_path = "C:\\Users\\akram\\Desktop\\Work\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe"

service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
url = "https://www.surfline.com/surf-report/meia-praia/5842041f4e65fad6a7708e84?view=table"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)

elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h4.MuiTypography-root.MuiTypography-headline.SurfCell_height__FkNCP.mui-style-1sd06dx')

for element in elements:
    print(element.text)

driver.quit()
```

Visit https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
To download the corresponding ChromeDriver with your chrome version and change the chrome_driver_path with yours and install selenium in python3 with: *pip install selenium*

Answer (score 0):

If the data itself is provided to the DOM through an API this is expected but how sure are you of your request?

I recommend tried the BeautifulSoup 4 expected way to scrap a css class, for example:

```
bs(req.content, 'html.parser').select(f'.test')
```